How to simply generate N colors?
I'm using D3 7.9 and can't find a way to simply generate N colors, for example, from rainbow. How do you do that outside the D3 way of doing things?
For example;
const categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', ..., ]
const n = parseFloat(categories.length);
const colors = d3.sequentialScale(d3.rainbowInterpolation);
const palette = categories.reduce((acc, category, i) => {
    return Object.assign(acc, {[category]: colors(parseFloat(i) / n});
 }


why parsing an integer?

convert it to float? to get a value between 0 and 1, isn't that what d3 expects? this is some pseudocode I wrote on my phone so just to give an idea of what I need.

Consider utilizing interpolateRainbow:


const N = 7;
const colors = Array.from({ length: N }, (_, i) => d3.interpolateRainbow(i / N));
const container = d3.select("#color-container");
container.selectAll(".color-box")
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "color-box")
  .style("background-color", d => d);
.color-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="color-container"></div>



If you for some reason only have access to interpolateRgb try something like this:


const N = 7;
const startColor = "red";
const endColor = "blue";
const interpolate = d3.interpolateRgb(startColor, endColor);
const colors = Array.from({ length: N }, (_, i) => interpolate(i / N));
console.log(colors);
const colorsHex = colors.map(color => d3.rgb(color).formatHex());
console.log(colorsHex);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>




Thanks a lot Sinha, I can't make it work, please see that the OP is about reusing the function outside the d3 way of doing things. If I try using the colors directly I can't because it is a collection of functions, if I then do the following I get all black colors: const colors = Array.from({ length: N }, (_, i) => d3.interpolateRgb(i / N)).map((f, i) => f(i / N)); I here get back a list of RGB(0, 0, 0) oh and I cant import interpolateRainbow but only interpolateRgb . I can't find interpolateRainbow in d3 7.9

I'm sorry but "I can't find interpolateRainbow in d3 7.9" doesn't make sense? I show I am importing 'd3 7.9.0" in the example and the linked docs also shows it is available in 7.9.0 in the top right.

thanks of never mind about the importing failing, I am on React and problably have an issue importing that dependency, though interpolateRgb works for me. How about just getting a plain list of RGB or color values, your colors variable holds a list of functions and then I am lost how to use the colors outside the "d3 way of doing things"

@SkyWalker Okay see my edit that only uses https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate/color#interpolateRgb
